# How would you draw "current in to page" and "current out of page" symbols?

Tags: symbols

So I need to draw a diagram that shows current densities, using the standard symbols for current going in to page and current out of page as seen below.  What is the best way to implement this?

[image]

Comment: If you draw your sketch with some of LaTeX packets, the simple way is draw this symbols by this package to. Show to us, what you try so far, than we will able to help you. Welcome to TeX. SE

Answer (score 1):

For current symbols you can use math symbols `\otimes` and `\odot` :). For more you should provide Minimal Working Example. Knowing it, I (or some one other) can suggest how to draw this symbols.

**Edit:**
In case of use `ciruitikz` package, you can include theses symbols in node. For example

```
\node[font=\huge,
      label={[align=left]right:CURRENT\\ FLOW OUT}] at (<coordinete>) {$\otimes$};
\node[font=\huge,
      label={[align=left]right:CURRENT\\ FLOW IN}] at (<coordinete>) {$\odot$};
```

or alternatively as suggested Alex:

```
\node[label={[align=left]right:CURRENT\\ FLOW OUT}] at (<coordinete>) {$\bigotimes$};
\node[label={[align=left]right:CURRENT\\ FLOW IN}] at (<coordinete>) {$\bigodot$};
```

Comment: You should mentioned in question, that you use `circuitikz` package! See edit of my answer.

Comment: Beat me to it...  But, I believe `\bigodot` and `\bigotimes` work better for this case.